# What HashMap and ArrayList are and what are they useful for?

Tags: java

I've read many times what HashMap and ArrayList are, but I still can't understand they use and how are they different from Vector for example.

Comment: If you've read the documents and couldn't understand them, what makes you think that an explanation here would be any help?

Comment: @PaulTomblin Don't want to help? Don't help

Comment: Read all of these: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/index.html, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: Oh, I'm helping all right.  I'm closing crap questions, which helps the site even if it doesn't help you.

Comment: @PaulTomblin Well good luck with that

Comment: @RoniCopul Paul Tomblin has a point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And `ArrayList` is a container of the family of `List`s that stores a sequence of objects such as "car1", "car2", etc...

A `HashMap` is a container of the type `Map` which maps keys to values, such as "car1 => red", "car2=>blue", etc...